# Android Studio EditText want a red line when field is empty and green when not empty

Tags: android

Im trying to make my first app and trying to indicate when the field is empty or not while on run..

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/elecCurrentEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/electPriviousEdit"
    android:layout_width="120sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for this goal.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing it is using a [hint](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html):

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/email_address"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/email_hint"
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check the edittext for empty string/character.

```
           if (editTextID.getText().toString().length() < 6)
                editTextID.setError("6 Characters!");  
           else{
                //some code here
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`write drawable xml in drawable folder in resources

don't forget to declare color in resources named borderColor.

and assign this background to the EditText

rounded_border_edittexterror.xml file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
         <corners android:radius="10dp" />
      <stroke
     android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#FFE70A2F"
     />
     </shape>
</selector>
```

rounded_border_edittext.xml file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
         <corners android:radius="10dp" />
      <stroke
     android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#FF5FAC16"
     />
     </shape>
  </selector>

  EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
  String sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
  if (sUsername.matches("")) 
  {               usernameEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_edittexterror);
 Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a  username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return;
}
  else {
  usernameEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_edittext);
  }
```